# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation in for-loop , but not while loop

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, cs50

I am working on the CS50 problem set 5 in C language. However, one of the function results in a VALGRIND error of "Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation". The function is used to load a bunch of words into the memory by using malloc to create a hash table of word and use it as a dictionary for spell checking later. The function is as follows and I quoted the error origin in **asterisk, which is the for-loop inside:

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");    
    if (dict == NULL)
        return false;

    char tempWord[LENGTH + 1];
    char buffer;
    int indexCount = 0;
    node *tempPointer = NULL;
    unsigned int tempHash = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        table[i] = NULL;


    while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), 1, dict) == 1)
    {
        if ((buffer != '\n') & (indexCount < LENGTH))
        {
            tempWord[indexCount] = buffer;
            indexCount += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tempWord[indexCount] = '\0';
            tempHash = hash(tempWord);
            tempPointer = table[tempHash];
            table[tempHash] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (table[tempHash] == NULL)
                return false;


           ******************************
           for (int i = 0; (tempWord[i] != '\0') & (i < LENGTH); i++)        
               table[tempHash]->word[i] = tempWord[i];
           *****************************                 


            table[tempHash]->next = tempPointer;
            wordCount += 1;
            indexCount = 0;
        }

    }
    fclose(dict);
   

    return true;
}
```

I don't know what is the problem. But when I change the for-loop into a while-loop, the memory error suddenly disappears. I would love to know why it would solve the problem as both loops have basically the same content.

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");    
    if (dict == NULL)
        return false;

    char tempWord[LENGTH + 1];
    char buffer;
    int indexCount = 0;
    node *tempPointer = NULL;
    unsigned int tempHash = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        table[i] = NULL;


    while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), 1, dict) == 1)
    {
        if ((buffer != '\n') & (indexCount < LENGTH))
        {
            tempWord[indexCount] = buffer;
            indexCount += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tempWord[indexCount] = '\0';
            tempHash = hash(tempWord);
            tempPointer = table[tempHash];
            table[tempHash] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (table[tempHash] == NULL)
                return false;

            ***************************
            int i = 0;
            while ((tempWord[i] != '\0') & (i < LENGTH))
            {
                table[tempHash]->word[i] = tempWord[i];
                i++;
            }           
            *******************

            table[tempHash]->next = tempPointer;
            wordCount += 1;
            indexCount = 0;
        }

    }
    fclose(dict);


    return true;
}
```

Comment: ASIDE: You should be using logical AND `&&`, not bitwise AND `&`.

Comment: You show way too little information. What is `table[tempHash]->word`? An array or a pointer? Also you fail to terminate the strings that you copy there.

Comment: @lan Abbott      Thx for the reminder. Didn't realize the silly mistake as the results come out correctly even using ```&```. But still, using either & or && still gives out the same VALGRIND error.

Comment: @Gerhardh   ```table``` is an array of pointers that each points to an object called node, which contains ```word``` that stores a ```char``` of size ```[LENGTH + 1]```. The node also contains ```next``` that is a pointer pointing to the next node. Basically the ```load``` function choose specific pointer from the ```table``` according to the first two characters of the word to be loaded, then the pointer from ```table``` point to the ```node``` that stores the loaded word and pointer to the next ```node``` storing another word.

Comment: I ran both versions; both produced the same valgrind errors. The problem is, as @Gerhardh pointed out, the unterminated strings in node->word. Perhaps look at [man strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

Comment: Please do not describe your code, show it. Show the declarations of the used types and definitions of used variables. Otherwise we cannot know whether your code is wrong or your description is not precise enough.

Comment: Thx guys. I think the problem indeed raised from not giving the ```\0``` to the ```char``` array. Is it automatically added for me when I directly assign a string to a ```char *``` variable, while I need to manually add it when manipulating ```char``` array?